# How to pass parameter between tags in smarty? Is there any command for it?

Tags: php, smarty

Let's imagine we have this HTML code:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-head">This is title</div>
    <div class="block-body">This is body</div>
</div>
```

Now, let's make TPL (myblock.tpl):

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-head">{$title}</div>
    <div class="block-body">{$body}</div>
</div>
```

I am able to do this now:

```
{include file="myblock.tpl" title="User Settings" body="<div>HELLO</div>"}
```

And result would be:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-head">User Settings</div>
    <div class="block-body"<div>HELLO</div></div>
</div>
```

But is there any way to do with smarty something like this?

```
{include file="myblock.tpl" title="User Settings"}
    <div>HELLO</div>
{/include}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are wanting to workaround the actual sense smarty was written for.

The documentation says there is no way to directly pass Markup to the template by putting it in between the include "tags".

It seems there are not many ways for solving you problem
but one would be composing a page-file like that:

...

```
{include file="myblock.tpl" title="User Settings"}
<div>HELLO</div>
{include 'footer.tpl'}
```

....

As an (apparently better) alternative "fetch" seems to be another solution:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/api.fetch.tpl
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.function.fetch.tpl

It will store a template's content within a variable which you could pass to your include like this:

```
{fetch file="myblock_body.tpl" assign="foo"}
{include file="myblock.tpl" title="User Settings" body=$foo}
```